# Linux C++ LibUSB Write Register in USB HUB

Tags: c++, linux, libusb

In Linux, I have a USB hub with the 'register' shown in the image below. This register is supposed to disable power on a certain port on the hub.

I tried to use LibUSB ( my code is shown below ) to write the register, 0x0A, with all zeros to disable all ports. The problem is, the hub is controlled by the standard Linux USB Hub driver and so the Kernel driver is detached. The write also fails. The failure messages are shown below.

Error messages:

```
$ /mnt/apps/UsbPowerControl
5 Devices in list.
Vendor:Device = 1908:1320
Vendor:Device = 0403:6001
Vendor:Device = 289d:0010
Vendor:Device = 0424:2513
Vendor:Device = 1d6b:0002
Opening Device = 0424:2513
Device Opened
Kernel Driver Active
Kernel Driver Detached!
Claimed Interface
Data-><-
Writing Data...
libusb: error [submit_bulk_transfer] submiturb failed error -1 errno=2
Write Error
Released Interface
```

How can I use LibUSB to write this Hub register, to dynamically disable and enable the ports, without unregistering the Linux driver and having my write fail?

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

using namespace std;

#define VENDOR_ID 0x0424
#define PRODUCT_ID 0x2513

int main() {

    libusb_device **devs; //pointer to pointer of device, used to retrieve a list of devices
    libusb_device_handle *dev_handle; //a device handle
    libusb_context *ctx = NULL; //a libusb session
    int r; //for return values
    ssize_t cnt; //holding number of devices in list
    r = libusb_init(&ctx); //initialize the library for the session we just declared
    if(r < 0) {
        cout<<"Init Error "<<r<<endl; //there was an error
        return 1;
    }
    libusb_set_debug(ctx, 3); //set verbosity level to 3, as suggested in the documentation

    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &devs); //get the list of devices
    if(cnt < 0) {
        cout<<"Get Device Error"<<endl; //there was an error
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<cnt<<" Devices in list."<<endl;

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < cnt; ++idx) {
        libusb_device *device = devs[idx];
        libusb_device_descriptor desc = {0};

        int rc = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc);
        assert(rc == 0);

        printf("Vendor:Device = %04x:%04x\n", desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct);
    }

    printf("Opening Device = %04x:%04x\n", VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);

    dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(ctx, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID); //these are vendorID and productID I found for my usb device
    if(dev_handle == NULL)
        cout<<"Cannot open device"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Device Opened"<<endl;
    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1); //free the list, unref the devices in it

    unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[1]; //data to write
    data[0]=0b00000000;

    int actual; //used to find out how many bytes were written
    if(libusb_kernel_driver_active(dev_handle, 0) == 1) { //find out if kernel driver is attached
        cout<<"Kernel Driver Active"<<endl;
        if(libusb_detach_kernel_driver(dev_handle, 0) == 0) //detach it
            cout<<"Kernel Driver Detached!"<<endl;
    }
    r = libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle, 0); //claim interface 0 (the first) of device (mine had jsut 1)
    if(r < 0) {
        cout<<"Cannot Claim Interface"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<"Claimed Interface"<<endl;
    cout<<"Data->"<<data<<"<-"<<endl; //just to see the data we want to write : abcd
    cout<<"Writing Data..."<<endl;
    r = libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, (0x0A | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT), data, 1, &actual, 0); //my device's out endpoint was 2, found with trial- the device had 2 endpoints: 2 and 129
    if(r == 0 && actual == 1) //we wrote the 1 bytes successfully
        cout<<"Writing Successful!"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Write Error"<<endl;

    r = libusb_release_interface(dev_handle, 0); //release the claimed interface
    if(r!=0) {
        cout<<"Cannot Release Interface"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<"Released Interface"<<endl;

    libusb_close(dev_handle); //close the device we opened
    libusb_exit(ctx); //needs to be called to end the

    delete[] data; //delete the allocated memory for data
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int libusb_detach_kernel_driver (   libusb_device_handle *  dev,
int     interface_number 
)   
...
If successful, you will then be able to claim the interface and perform I/O.
...



int libusb_kernel_driver_active (   libusb_device_handle *  dev,
int     interface_number 
)   
...
If a kernel driver is active, you cannot claim the interface, and libusb will be unable to perform I/O.
...
```

Due to what is written above, the short answer to the question "How to do I/O without detaching driver" is "You can't".

Why write fails? This is another matter. I'd suggest looking into a number of things:

1. Check out the value returned from libusb_bulk_transfer, maybe it will give you the idea of what is happening.
2. Sounds stupid, but I always check it out before anything else: process privileges.

Also, I can suggest another way of approaching the solution, namely sysfs.

I assume that [your device(am I right?)](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/155993/Smsc-Usb2524.html?page=21#manual) supports EEPROM and SMBus access. It means that this support should be manifested in the kernel somewhere around **/sys/bus/i2c/devices/[some_device_id]/eeprom** (probably another device number, another directory position, etc, because it is all driver-related), but if it can be found and read just as any other file (which is likely, unless something is wrong with the device), then it probably should be able to write into it as well. If the read works, then I suggest to compare the **hexdump -C** of the found file to the datasheet, and if the data seems legit, try writing directly into your register(file offset).

Anyway, accessing character device files and sysfs files is a general way of accessing drivers' data in linux. Probably you don't even need to use libusb's API to write that single byte.